# Angular2 development in Visual Studio 2015 without downloading Node modules

Tags: visual-studio-2015, angular

Is there a way to build an Angular2 Typescript app without having to download to node_modules?

Previously, I only had to only download DefinitelyTyped and load the libraries through CDN during execution.

Now, the recommendation is to download to node_modules, which causes problems because of the deeply nested files and folders, even if I dedupe or flatten them.

I also would like to avoid having to deal with build errors related to scripts within Angular2 and dependencies.

UPDATE

I found out that setting up Angular2 in Visual Studio 2015 requires another approach. I followed the steps in [Starting Angular 2 in ASP.NET 5 with TypeScript using Visual Studio 2015](http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/) and I didn't get any build issues anymore.

Comment: Use the latest version of node and npm and you won't get the deep folder nesting problem.

Comment: I have. But now it's not able to build because of other issues within node_modules\angular2. I'd like to avoid them altogether.

Comment: Check out the same article for updated with Angular 2 RC, also no harm in downloading them and using it. Only during deployment if we package only needed files then its good.